# Cannot convert Django Queryset to a List

Tags: python, django

I created the following query:

```
my_books = Book.objects.values('title') 
print(my_books)
```

The output is:

```
<QuerySet [{'title': 'It do go down'}, {'title': 'Second Post'}, {'title': 'Tesla - A New Generation'}]>
```

Now I want to change the QuerySet to give me back a list which should look like this:

```
['It do go down', 'Second Post', 'Tesla - A New Generation']
```

What do I have to do in order to get the result above?

PS: What I tried was an answer to a related question: `print(list(my_books))` which showed the following:

```
[{'title': 'It do go down'}, {'title': 'Second Post'}, {'title': 'Tesla - A New Generation'}]
```

Furthermore I tried an iteration, which didn't work at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a list, you should use `values_list`.

```
my_books = Book.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)
```

The `flat=True` parameter makes it a flat list, rather than a list of lists.